# Join two dataset by nearest id without filling in the gaps

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to do a full join between two datasets df_a and df_b of unequal lengths based on IDs, which are depths, that do not exactly match. The idea is to merge each entry from df_b to **only one** entry from df_a that share the closest ID with df_b.

Here is an example of data:

```
Depth_a <- seq(1, 10)
value_a <- c(10, 12, 8, 5, 20, 33, 0, 3, 5, 14)
df_a <- tibble(Depth_a, value_a)

# A tibble: 10 × 2
   Depth_a value_a
     <int>   <dbl>
 1       1      10
 2       2      12
 3       3       8
 4       4       5
 5       5      20
 6       6      33
 7       7       0
 8       8       3
 9       9       5
10      10      14

Depth_b <- c(1.2, 3.2, 7.2, 10.2)
value_b <- c(4, 8, 14, 17)
df_b <- tibble(Depth_b, value_b)

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  Depth_b value_b
    <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1.2       4
2     3.2       8
3     7.2      14
4    10.2      17
```

The idea is to merge the values at depths 1 and 1.2, 3 and 3.2, etc, and only keeping the id from df_a. I have tried doing a full_join with the join_by function now included in dplyr:

```
full_join(df_a, df_b, join_by(closest(Depth_a <= Depth_b)))
```

However, the results is not what I want:

```
What I get: 
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   Depth_a value_a Depth_b value_b
     <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1       1      10     1.2       4
 2       2      12     3.2       8
 3       3       8     3.2       8
 4       4       5     7.2      14
 5       5      20     7.2      14
 6       6      33     7.2      14
 7       7       0     7.2      14
 8       8       3    10.2      17
 9       9       5    10.2      17
10      10      14    10.2      17

What I want: 
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   Depth_a value_a Depth_b value_b
     <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1       1      10     1.2       4
 2       2      12     NA       NA
 3       3       8     3.2       8
 4       4       5     NA       NA
 5       5      20     NA       NA
 6       6      33     NA       NA
 7       7       0     7.2      14
 8       8       3     NA       NA
 9       9       5     NA       NA
10      10      14    10.2      17 

And the final cleaned merged dataset: 

# A tibble: 10 × 4
   Depth value_a   value_b
     <int>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1       1      10      4
 2       2      12     NA
 3       3       8      8
 4       4       5     NA
 5       5      20     NA    
 6       6      33     NA     
 7       7       0     14    
 8       8       3     NA      
 9       9       5     NA      
10      10      14     17
```

In summary, I want to fully join both dataset by the closest ID (depth) match, but without creating new data. For example, I want depth 10.2 from df_b to ONLY merge with depth 10 from df_a, and let the depth from 8-9 with NA.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

******EDIT******

I found something which works (see below). However, I was still wondering if there was a more direct way to achieve the results, without the intermediate steps?

Comment: Having the same name (Depth) for both IDs will result in ```Depth.x``` and ```Depth.y```, giving the same overall results in the end, I think.

Comment: Your code is inconsistent (I've rolled back my edit). You define `Depth` and then make a tibble referencing `Depth_b`. We can work with having same-names, it's easy enough, but having different names works too. My point is that your code is inconsistent, not any commentary on naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

From OP:

> Here is a work-around that I found:

```
df_a %>% 
  full_join(df_b, join_by(closest(Depth_a <= Depth_b))) %>% # This merges both dataset but by dyplicating Depth_b and value_b
  mutate(ID_diff = abs(Depth_a - Depth_b)) %>% # This calculate the difference between Depth_b and Depth_a
  group_by(value_b) %>% #group by the duplicated value_b
  slice_min(ID_diff) %>% #choose the row with the smaller difference between Depth_a and Depth_b, i.e., the closest match. 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(c("Depth_a", "value_b")) %>%
  full_join(df_a, by = c("Depth_a")) %>% # Re-join the datasets
  arrange(Depth_a)
```

> Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   Depth_a value_b value_a
     <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1       1       4      10
 2       2      NA      12
 3       3       8       8
 4       4      NA       5
 5       5      NA      20
 6       6      NA      33
 7       7      14       0
 8       8      NA       3
 9       9      NA       5
10      10      17      14
```

NB- Another way of doing what OP did is:

```
cross_join(df_a, df_b) %>%
  mutate(diff = abs(id_a - id_b)) %>%
  filter(diff == min(diff), .by = id_b) %>%
  full_join(df_a, by = "id_a") %>%
  select(id_a, value_a = value_a.y, id_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing the same thing:

```
process<- function(a, b, v) {
  out <- rep(NA, length(a))
  for (i in seq_along(b)) {
    out[which.min(abs(a - b[i]))] <- v[i]
    }
  out
}
df_a$value_b <- process(df_a$id_a, df_b$id_b, df_b$value_b)
```